# Using Custom CSS Styles in Sitecore Rich Text Editor

Tags: css, sitecore, rich-text-editor

Trying to figure out exactly what the limitations are, if any, in the Sitecore CMS Rich Text Editor fields when not using pre-loaded styles or modifying the Telerik RadEditor control. Basically want to know how far we can go using on page custom styles with the style tag. Will we run into any conflicts with existing pre-loaded CSS?

Answer (score 0):

When committing style tags or inline styles to any RTE, it can be done, but don't do it.  For one, if other editors are not aware of it, they can over write those styles with one change.  Also style tags in the body of a web page will violate accessibility standards (depending on if your company needs to be 501 compliant).  Also if your designer's classes are overridden, on the page it can be a nightmare to fix and maintain.

Recommendation: Typically I would make all CSS options for a rendering as rendering parameters, but if you really need embedded CSS, I would make a new text field on the template of the page/content, and have the developer pull that CSS correctly into the layout.

Here's a link, it's a bit dated but it does a good job explaining rendering parameters, which is the path I highly recommend:

https://sitecoretricks.wordpress.com/2018/03/31/understanding-the-rendering-parameters/